# Do Android Wear devices have an IP-address?

Tags: android

Android Wear devices use bluetooth to connect to the internet, via your smartphone.
Does this mean the Smartwatch has its own IP on the local network?

Comment: No necessarily. All the calls between Android Phone and Android Wear is made via bluetooth.

Comment: That's too bad. So we can't send requests over IP?

Answer (score -1):

Probably too late to reply but yes android wear devices do indeed have their own IP.

One way to find out is to debug over wifi under dev options. Once connected correctly, it should display its IP on the network with port 5555.

Alternatively, disable Bluetooth on the device, enable wifi and scan the network. Android wear favours Bluetooth connectivity so its important to disable it.